# Is this potential XSS exploitable?

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, vulnerability, web

I am pentesting a website and I found that I can inject code at `value=""`

```
<input type="text" id="search_1" name="keyword" placeholder="Search by keyword" value="XSS?" class="search-input input-group-field with-floating-label" data-module="autocomplete" required>`
```

I can enter all characters except double quotes (") because it encodes them for me.

So, my questions is, can I exploit XSS without leaving the `value = " "` or is there any way to get out of the value?

Comment: What about: ``<input onmouseover=prompt(1)>``? Assuming it is displayed in the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you can't enter double quotes you cannot escape from the attribute value. See the [WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attribute-value-(double-quoted)-state) for details on how browsers parse attribute values. The possible parser state transitions in that state are:

| character | effect |
| --- | --- |
| `"` double quote | end attribute value |
| `&` ampersand | parse a character reference |
| NULL | error, but will continue parse |
| EOF | error, will end parse |
| other characters | added to attribute value |

So unless there is a bug in the HTML parser, you cannot escape. The `&` ampersand is the only interesting character in this context, but it does not lead to parser states that would terminate the attribute value. A null character will be substituted with the U+FFFD replacement character, so it will not lead to interesting behaviour in the browser.

However, the web application will do something interesting with that input value. Maybe this “something” will have exploitable vulnerabilities if you can provide a specially prepared value.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced this kind of situation. The developers has sanitized `"` to prevent XSS vulnerability. You cannot get rid of `"`.

And inside the double quote is a single `string` while the attribute is `value`. So, you cannot exploit it. Because to exploit you have to bring input out of the double quote anyway.